# What is a group and its operation?

Tags: group-theory, definition, cyclic-groups

I am learning group theory by myself and has not reached cyclic groups yet but as I have read cyclic groups are group generated by a single element and is denoted as $G = \langle x, *\rangle$ where $*$ is a operation.

I have some questions:

1. Can this $*$ be a function? I think yes it can be a function. Because every operation is a kind of function.

If yes, then will the following is a group, specifically cyclic group:

2. $G = \langle x, 26(x^2+8x) \mod 103\rangle$ where $x = 2$. I think yes and no (I am confused). Yes because it generates a cyclic group of order $9$, $G = [2, 5, 42, 10, 45, 4, 12, 60, 93]$. No because the operator here is a unary operation that would not be able to combine two elements of group.

I might have made an error in notation so please ask in comments for any clarification.

Comment: $*$ has to be a binary operation. It is a function, but it cannot really be a function of one variable. In your example, what is $2*5$? I don't see how it is defined by your function.

Comment: $*$ is a function as in for $x,y,z\in G$, $* : x \times y \mapsto z$

Comment: @Malady please read new edit regarding unary operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your confusion seems to be about the meaning of the phrase "generated by".

- with its informal meaning, it is true that starting from the element $2\bmod{103}$, the function $f:\Bbb Z/(103\Bbb Z)\to \Bbb Z/(103\Bbb Z),\;x\mapsto26(x^2+8x)$ "generates" the ***subset*** $G:=\{2, 5, 42, 10, 45, 4, 12, 60, 93\}$, more precisely: $f(2)=5,f(5)=42,\dots,f(60)=93,f(93)=5$, and then the sequence repeats periodically.
  But as long as you don't equip this set $G$ with some *binary* operation (i.e. some function from $G\times G$ to $G$), you have no opportunity to claim it to be (or not to be) [a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)).
- with the formal and specific meaning of group theory, one generally speaks of a [***group $G$ generated by***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group) a subset $S\subseteq G$. The group $G$ here is supposed to be already given, implicitely equipped with its binary operation. In the special case where $S$ is a singleton $\{s\}$, one says that $G$ is generated by $S$ or simply by $s$, if every element of $G$ is of the form $s^k$ (if the binary operation of the group is denoted mutiplicatively, $\cdot$) or $ks$ (if it is denoted additively, $+$) for some integer $k$. For instance the group $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is generated by $1$ and the group $(\{1,i,-1,-i\},\cdot)$ is generated by [$i$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit).

Comment: Two further question: Is there a name for the structure in the question, can this structure be isomorphic to another structure of same order under unary operation? Is there a way to find the binary operation $*$?

Comment: These are 3 questions, and should be asked in a new post. 1) May be "the ***orbit*** of $2$ under $f$", though one usually prefers $f$ to be bijective when using this word. 2) Yes, e.g. $G':=\{a,b,\dots,i,j\}$, $f'(a)=b,f'(b)=c,\dots,f'(i)=j,f'(j)=b.$ 3) There is no specific binary operation on such a structure. On a set $X$ with 10 elements, there are many binary operations which make it a group: consider one of the two non isomorphic groups $G_1,G_2$ with 10 elements (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups), and use a bijection between $X$ and $G_i$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure

Answer (score 1):

Each group requires a *binary* operation, which, yes, is a kind of function. Each binary operation takes *two* things (that may be duplicates) as input to work, not one.

> **Definition:** A group $(G,\circ)$ is a set $G$ under a binary operation
>
> $$\circ:G\times G\to G$$
>
> that is closed (by definition of a binary operation), associative, has an identity element $e\in G$, and each element of $G$ has an inverse in $G$ with respect to $e$.

Your candidate group does not have a binary operation, so cannot be a group.

To say that the set of integers you list is a group is mistaken. Remember, you need, in addition to the set, the binary operation; and the same set can produce different groups under different binary operations.

---

It looks like you are trying to run before you can walk. Try a few more basic exercises in group theory ahead of tackling cyclic groups.

Answer (score 0):

A superfast overview:

there's only one cyclic group of order $n$, and the prototype is $(\Bbb Z_n,+)$ with addition.   The integers modulo $n$.  Addition is used because the group is abelian (commutative).

The infinite cyclic group is the integers $(\Bbb Z,+)$.

Those are all the cyclic groups.

Comment: Yes.  That's why I said prototype.   @Malady

Comment: Okay, my apologies. I missed that.

Comment: $(n\mathbb Z,+)$ is also an infinite cyclic group (isomorphic to ($\mathbb Z,+)$)